# SWIFT. Verification of the document signature issue. 64 bytes instead of 71

Tags: c#, swift, cryptography, sign, ecdsa

I have a task to verify of signature compliance for the metadata, but for some reason all the methods that I used return 'false'. The document is signed via C # in the following way:

```
//Cert format X509Certificate2
var ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey());
byte[] signature;
signature = ecdsa.SignData(bufferedFileStream, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);
```

And we get the signature with size = 64 bytes

But swift native method generate signature with size = 71 bytes:

```
let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(privateKey,
                                      .ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256,
                                      fileData as CFData,
                                      &signError)
```

Certificate generated with ECDSA NIST p256
Sig. Algorithm - ecdsa-with-SHA256

Till now I tried 3 ways of ways of checking:

```
//1
SecKeyVerifySignature(publicKey,
                      .ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256,
                      fileData as CFData,
                      signature as! CFData,
                      &error)
//2
SecKeyRawVerify(publicKey,
                .PKCS1SHA512,
                hashedDataBytes,
                digestLength,
                signatureBytes,
                signatureData.count)
//3
let publicKeyP265 = try! P256.Signing.PublicKey(x963Representation: bytesArray)
let ecdsaSignature = try! P256.Signing.ECDSASignature(rawRepresentation: signature)             
let result = publicKeyP265.isValidSignature(ecdsaSignature, for: fileData)
```

The result is negative for each method

So far, I have not been able to achieve success and validate the signature, perhaps someone has encountered a similar problem.

Comment: I see `SHA512` in the C# code, but only ONE of your different tries try to use the same one...

Comment: @Larme Which one?

Comment: See : https://transactionfee.info/charts/bitcoin-script-ecdsa-length/?force_isolation=true and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm?force_isolation=true

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem with next code:

```
    let publicKeyP265 = try! P256.Signing.PublicKey(x963Representation: bytesArray)
    let ecdsaSignature = try! P256.Signing.ECDSASignature(rawRepresentation: signature)
    let fileDataDigest = SHA512.hash(data: fileData)
    
    let result = publicKeyP265.isValidSignature(ecdsaSignature, for: fileDataDigest)
```

I hope it will be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the signature when using ECDSA and P256 is not the same as the size of the digest. ECDSA signatures are normally encoded into a DER format. You'll have the overhead of DER bytes as well as the additional sign bytes (whether or not an integer is signed or unsigned).

Below I've written a simple example using python and the cryptography library. You can see that the output size of the signature is almost always 70 or more. I've also printed the hexadecimal representation of the DER signature.

The size of the hash here is very likely to be irrelevant. The biggest difference of the signature has to do with the key size of the EC key.

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec

message = b'Hello World'

for i in range(0, 10):
    sig = ec.generate_private_key(ec.SECP256R1()).sign(message, ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA512()))
    print(f'{i}: {len(sig)} {sig.hex()}')

# 0: 71 30450221008466be7ca99fd80bc37527c078c30d07b725dd79feeb29816723259d27ccc367022051f1df8edbf82f528d587ce4db49e99b67cc6e8e61d83d90bfa050195c940721
# 1: 72 3046022100f478984dc0bccfb789713ab2ebb1636115ddaf55c7e8e44ba0c3b076e286def8022100a7ece3201a6cf521838a497510aede841bdc5ab2c59d225c2675a52b221419f6
# 2: 71 3045022100c6e8cfc1872f7aaa4d5c348bee5956ec7dc91422c07f382c402ac6d4265339f802206464c4e7d5d17b0bf28ba9b73cd16d4f1d59aa51d30144431a9367d3eb4fad78
# 3: 71 304502206ee73053a0479de84d1f5786705d121d9342bf1cc6d189fdfd30d55600e72b12022100efb16d5f5a4c7c1d60346e4c22395c955fa2abb2eb30f6649b1ee2c6921ac65a
# 4: 71 304502203a4f2ccec95a94b8b564a5abc837e39b33d338ad4c5ae421316644caac905722022100f78091452346154de97efdf7635c0c6bf74129e4868cd1c870f9b6ccbd20deac
# 5: 71 3045022100d960be8e6196de3e20098438783dfd8347163e5e78c631c592f1198ce3ffe1ef0220537a8e6efcbdcea3f15949c2896c88bd1b164474d34a367a33459e1db31b93d1
# 6: 72 3046022100a08a9e9cedec4341958b6690114a8e5569059e6c0bff3687acc3f49b53f3e105022100857932764645c8a195f4dd18820f12560be2ba2785fc745d49204aace2ebcfd8
# 7: 71 304502210087af13607c190d1656b0fc5d31b303f2616a92a7f516d5f528e8da59a61c0105022009094047f82158a6aca1b17ce6b276dc7122b7ecfebda7c517b6ab8770e40955
# 8: 71 3045022100885d72c1b31058f024d73d2a096cc662d847caf9db59b8483dd963fb70e6c3950220147ee83c980e2d866228c152e5c711817d3e60e60b7abff867ab9bd15b658777
# 9: 70 304402203eeb8b566a3198888bada3d346ab0caf7e14a882d1521120bee679209af2e4200220636100e9a6cd10386a9830a6c2885ee1fdfe00958473adb4bab1a85a0e3c8b11
```

So to answer your question, set the signature using a DER format:

```
var ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
byte[] signature;
signature = ecdsa.SignData(bufferedFileStream, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence);
```

You can find the documentation of the function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.signdata?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_ECDsa_SignData_System_IO_Stream_System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithmName_System_Security_Cryptography_DSASignatureFormat_) and the supported formats [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.dsasignatureformat?view=net-5.0).